# Cisco VPN Concepts - Connection Profiles and Group Policy

Tags: firewall, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn

I was wondering could someone please explain the main concepts of how Cisco ASA Firewalls implement VPNs please? Specifically what are Connection Profiles and Group Policies used for? i.e. What they do, how they work.

I've a strong theoretical understanding of VPNs but no pratical experience. At present I'm just learning the basics using a Cisco ASA Simulator.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection Profiles are used to assign DHCP servers, Global Addresse Pools, AAA and generic VPN settings. (How to connect to the VPN)

It will also be "linked" to a Group Policiy"

The Group Policy will specify network ACL, DNS and Routing (Split Tunneling) once the VPN connection is established. (What are you privileges once you are connected)

Therefore, you can have multiple ways to connect to your VPN endpoint but still have the same policies attributed to the different VPN clients.